# Boas práticas com .NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, razor

Tenho uma aplicação ASP.NET MVC e gostaria de saber quais são as boas práticas que a microsoft indica no quesito organizacional da solução, utilizando as tecnologias mais recentes como ASP.NET Identity.

Assumindo o seguinte cenário:

> - Controller para usuário (UsuarioController);
> - ViewModel para as actions de usuário;
> - Classe que representa a entidade usuário;
> - Classe que representa o repositorio de usuário;
> - Algumas Views de usuário possui imagens;
> - Algumas Views de usuário possuem scripts e css's específicos.

Como posso organizar o cenário acima? Isto é, onde devo escrever o código de todas as ViewModels? Estas devem estar no mesmo local que a entidade usuário? E as imagens de uma View específica, devem ficar agrupadas na pasta Content?

Comment: Você está considerando o uso de alguma arquitetura que a Microsoft já definiu, como o ASP.NET Membership ou então o ASP.NET Identity?

Comment: Estou considerando um meio geral em que possa ser utilizado como base para projetos que utilizem ou não o Membership ou o Identity.

Comment: @Vinícius, ViewModel é para você fazer um melhor bind e tipagem nas suas Views, além de não deixar feio com todas aquelas annotations, "imagens" ? bom, hoje no cenário atual, nem se armazena mais imagens em pastas, se sua app for cloud, mas se caso não for, você coloca na estrutura que você quiser, não tem uma "regra" para isso

Comment: Isso não dá. A resposta ficaria enorme.

Comment: @Rod, o questionamento seria mais em onde implementar este código. Do modo que faço atualmente, minha entidade e as viewmodels do contexto do meu controller (UsuarioController) ficam dentro de um arquivo chamado UsuarioModel dentro da pasta Models. Contudo, não sei se esta é a forma mais adequada de se implementar.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez, não há um modo ou convenção mais indicada para aplicações pequenas que utilizam apenas o ASP.NET MVC? Sem a utilização de bibliotecas de negócio que utilizam arquiteturas mais complexas como N-Camadas ou Onion...

Comment: Se a aplicação é pequena, a própria separação do MVC já basta, isso é, depende do que você está citando "pequeno"

Comment: @Vinícius A partir do MVC5 o indicado é usar o ASP.NET Identity. Eu preciso que você delimite essa resposta pra que eu possa responder algo objetivamente.

Comment: @Vinícius Para Models, Controllers e Views, siga o padrão da própria MS. Crie um template e veja, é o que a MS recomenda. O resto você segue de uma pasta para cada. E o mais importante: UM ARQUIVO para cada!! Sem Entidade e ViewModel no mesmo arquivo!!

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez, editei a pergunta para o ASP.NET Identity, já que como você citou, é o mais indicado para se utilizar.

Comment: @AndreFigueiredo, o template de um projeto ASP.NET MVC 4 possui viewmodels dentro de um mesmo arquivo. Você poderia responder porque não é indicado utilizar?

Comment: @Vinícius Não é indicado pela organização e navegação dentro dos fontes. Não separar tende a virar bagunça depois de um tempo. O certo seria a Microsoft ter separado.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Primeiramente, estou assumindo a organização para ASP.NET Identity, para que a resposta não vire uma muralha de texto.

Assumindo o seguinte cenário:

> - Controller para usuário (UsuarioController);
> - ViewModel para as actions de usuário;
> - Classe que representa a entidade usuário;
> - Classe que representa o repositorio de usuário;
> - Algumas Views de usuário possui imagens;
> - Algumas Views de usuário possuem scripts e css's específicos.

## Como posso organizar o cenário acima?

No ASP.NET Identity isso já vem organizado pra você da seguinte forma:

- *Controller* para o Usuário: `Controllers/AccountController`;
- *ViewModels* para as Actions de Usuário: `Models/AccountViewModel`;
- Classe que representa a entidade Usuário: `ApplicationUser`, em `Models/IdentityModels`. Isto não significa que entidades adicionais devam ficar no fonte `IdentityModels`. O melhor é deixar um fonte por classe;
- Classe que representa o repositório de Usuário: Se você está usando Entity Framework, o Entity Framework **é o repositório não apenas de Usuário, mas de todas as entidades do sistema**. Numa aplicação ASP.NET MVC5, ele está dentro de `ApplicationDbContext` (`Models/IdentityModels`), derivado de `IdentityDbContext`, que contém um `IDbSet<TUser> Users`. Este `Users` é o repositório;
- Algumas *Views* de usuário possui imagens: Você pode salvar as imagens do usuário em banco de dados, no diretório da aplicação `Content/Images` ou então usar o [Gravatar](https://gravatar.com).
- Algumas Views de usuário possuem scripts e CSS's específicos: Você teria que montar `@section`s dinamicamente. Normalmente o projeto vem configurado com duas: `scripts` e `views`. Veja seu arquivo `_Layout.cshtml` para ver onde essas *sections* serão escritas. Não vale a pena colocar isso aqui. Essa parte merece uma pergunta em separado.

## Onde devo escrever o código de todas as ViewModels? Estas devem estar no mesmo local que a entidade usuário?

Em um diretório `ViewModels`, separado dos demais diretórios (`Models`, `Controller`, `Views`, ...).

## E as imagens de uma View específica, devem ficar agrupadas na pasta Content?

Sim. Normalmente uso `Content\Images\MinhaView\`. Você pode criar quantos subdiretórios quiser a partir disso. Apenas não esqueça de definir um arquivo `index.html` para cada nível, para evitar problemas com a publicação (se os diretórios estão vazios, o Web Deploy não cria os diretórios no destino da publicação).

Comment: As demais entidades do sistema também devem permanecer em Models/IdentityModels?

Comment: De jeito nenhum. Separadas por arquivo. Vou editar a resposta assim que a conexão de internet deixar.