# EntityFramework 6 + LazyLoadingEnabled + using()

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6, lazy-loading, repository

Preciso de um help. Meu problema é o seguinte: Não consigo retornar os itens do meu objeto.

Segue meu código para analise.

### Classe Cliente

```
public partial class Cliente
{
    public Cliente()
    {
        this.ClienteEndereco = new HashSet<ClienteEndereco>();
    }

    public int IdCliente { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ClienteEndereco> ClienteEndereco { get; set;}
}
```

### Classe ClienteEndereco

```
public partial class ClienteEndereco
{
    public int IdClienteEndereco { get; set; }
    public int IdCliente { get; set; }
    public int IdCidade { get; set; }
    public string Endereco { get; set; }

    public virtual Cidade Cidade { get; set; }
    public virtual Cliente Cliente { get; set; }
}
```

### Método de consulta

```
    public IList<T> ListarTudo()
    {
        using (MeuContext context = new MeuContext())
        {
            context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;

            return context.Set<T>().ToList();
        }
    }
```

Quando chamo minha consulta os itens do ClienteEndero me retornam `Count = 0`:

```
var clientes = repositorioCliente.ListarTudo();
```

Sei que se eu colocar o no método de consulta Include("ClienteEndereco") ele irá retornar todos meus itens, porem esse método é genérico, então alterei o método passando os includes necessários.

```
    public List<T> ListaTudo(string[] includes)
    {
        using (MeuContext context = new MeuContext())
        {
            IQueryable<T> query = context.Set<T>();
            if (includes != null)
                foreach (var includeProperty in includes)
                {
                    query = query.Include(includeProperty);
                }
            return query.ToList();
        }
    }
```

Mas agora, toda chamada que eu fizer lá no meu *Controller* (MVC) para todos os métodos eu terei que passar a lista de includes necessários.

```
private readonly RepositorioGenerico<Cliente> repositorioCliente = new RepositorioGenerico<Cliente>();

private string[] includes = {"ClienteEndereco","ClienteEndereco.Cidade"};

var Clientes = repositorioCliente.ListaTudo(includes);
```

Além de achar que meu código está ficando muito poluído estou tendo muito trabalho para mapear em todos os *Controllers* os *Includes* necessários, só para lá na minha *View* não estourar o erro de:

> "The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer ...."

Tem alguma outra forma de trazer os itens sem que eu necessite utilizar *Includes*?

Answer (score 4):

Se você está tendo muito trabalho, significa que está usando a ferramenta errado, e isto é evidente pela sua explicação.

Pelo jeito não vou poder cansar de dizer que **o Entity Framework jé é um repositório, então você não precisa implementar outro repositório**. Veja as respostas que já dei a respeito:

- [Entity Framework DDD Infra repositório Genérico](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/40577/entity-framework-ddd-infra-reposit%c3%b3rio-gen%c3%a9rico/40585?s=3|2.1874#40585)
- [Unidade de trabalho (Unit of Work) com repositório](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/33280/unidade-de-trabalho-unit-of-work-com-reposit%c3%b3rio/33285?s=6|1.8674#33285)
- [Lugar em que devem ficar métodos de interação do CRUD com o banco em ASP.NET MVC](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/43637/duvida-mvc-asp-net-crud/43682?s=13|0.2136#43682)
- [Como manter sempre 1 registro no BD após inserir com entityframework?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/54141/como-manter-sempre-1-registro-no-bd-ap%c3%b3s-inserir-com-entityframework/54145?s=14|0.1914#54145)
- [EF6 erro de EntityValidationErrors em propriedade preenchida](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/63953/ef6-erro-de-entityvalidationerrors-em-propriedade-preenchida/64606?s=17|0.1562#64606)
- [Boas práticas com .NET MVC](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/41411/boas-pr%c3%a1ticas-com-net-mvc/41418?s=18|0.1509#41418)
- [problema com update Entity Framework 6](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/58425/problema-com-update-entity-framework-6/58446?s=22|0.1221#58446)
- [Camada de Aplicação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/31664/camada-de-aplica%c3%a7%c3%a3o/31668?s=24|0.1035#31668)
- [Como funciona o Tracking / Chache de objetos do EntityFramework?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/63058/como-funciona-o-tracking-chache-de-objetos-do-entityframework/63071?s=31|0.0194#63071)

## Sobre *Model* `Cliente`

Isto não precisa ser feito. O Entity Framework controla as propriedades de navegação automaticamente, então nada precisa ser inicializado. A parte abaixo pode ser retirada do código:

```
public Cliente()
{
    this.ClienteEndereco = new HashSet<ClienteEndereco>();
}
```

## Sobre o Método de Consulta

Não há motivo pra você desativar o *Lazy Load* neste momento. Ele só se justifica caso você tenha uma massa muito grande de registros para usar, o que dificilmente é o caso.

Além disso, esta construção aqui:

```
return context.Set<T>().ToList();
```

Faz o Entity Framework realizar um [`FULL TABLE SCAN`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Full_table_scan) no seu banco de dados. O correto é montar a sentença no `DbSet` e só usar `.ToList()` com a devida parametrização. Ou seja, está construção é **péssima** para o desempenho.

## Sobre o problema do `Include`

Os problemas que você está tendo ocorrem pela insistência de você usar um repositório genérico onde não precisa.

Este tipo de construção é completamente desnecessária e deve ser abandonada:

```
public List<T> ListaTudo(string[] includes)
{
    using (MeuContext context = new MeuContext())
    {
        IQueryable<T> query = context.Set<T>();
        if (includes != null)
            foreach (var includeProperty in includes)
            {
                query = query.Include(includeProperty);
            }
        return query.ToList();
    }
}
```

Se preciso listar tudo, como por exemplo clientes, posso fazer apenas:

```
var clientes = context.Clientes.ToList();
```

Se preciso carregar dados do cliente e quero carregar por `JOIN` endereços, posso fazer da seguinte forma:

```
var clientes = context.Clientes.Include(c => c.ClienteEndereco).ToList();
```

Ou seja, **não há qualquer motivo pra continuar uma implementação com repositório genérico**. Simplesmente use o Entity Framework como mostram os tutoriais que a otimização dos dados ocorre naturalmente em quase todos os casos.

Para outros casos, pergunte aqui no site.